# Fast Retransmit

Tags: tcp

I have following doubt regarding Fast retransmitting.
First of all i will Explain Fast retransmit.

> Fast Retransmit-:If a sender has  send packet P,P+1,P+2...P+N and let Packet P is  lost ,Now Reciever is expecting Packet P.Reciever will send 3 Duplicate Ack to sender "expecting Packet P".Sender on recieving  3 Duplicate Ack,Retransmit Packet P.

My doubt-:

- **What Happens to Packet P+1,P+2,...,P+N ?**
- Do sender Need to retransmit Packet P+1,P+2....P+N also??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full process in details is described in RFC 2581 3.2

The fast retransmit enhancement works as follows: if a TCP sender receives a specified number of acknowledgements which is usually set to three duplicate acknowledgements with the same acknowledge number (that is, a total of four acknowledgements with the same acknowledgement number), the sender can be reasonably confident that the **segment with the next higher sequence number was dropped**, and will not arrive out of order. The sender will then retransmit the packet that was presumed dropped before waiting for its timeout.